# How do I transform a function defined with pattern matching into an equivalent lambda?

Tags: haskell

How do I write

```
f 0 = 1
f x = (f(x-1))*2 + 2
```

as a lambda in Haskell?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Remove the x from the left hand side, add \x -> to the right.

Comment: f 0 = 1
f = f(\x-> -1))*2 +2 ?

Answer (score 5):

You'd move the pattern matching from the right and use a `case` expression

```
f = \ x -> case x of
  0 -> 1
  x -> f (x-1) * 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f = \x -> if x == 0 then 1 else (f (x - 1)) * 2 + 2
```